# move page number in a standard book shell

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using a standard Latex book shell to typeset a book. Does anyone know how to format page numbering  as follows:

1. for preliminary pages, e.g. title page, contents, preface, etc., put page number at the bottom-center;
2. for mainmatter, put page number at the top-right.

I tried the follows

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
```

However, they also move the page numbers of preliminary pages to top right which are not desired.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You can highlight code blocks by indenting with 4 spaces or by clicking the `{}` icon above the edit window. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can define two page styles; one for the preliminary pages and the other one for the mainmatter. Inside your document you can select the desired style using `\pagestyle`. A little example in which I named the two styles `preliminary` and `mainmatter`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{preliminary}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{preliminary}}
}
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{mainmatter}}
}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{preliminary}
\lipsum[1-12]

\clearpage
\pagestyle{mainmatter}
\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```